# Wordpress blank screen in localhost

Tags: php, database, wordpress, xampp, localhost

So I am trying to take my exciting wordpress blog from a live site and put into my localhost. I am using XAMPP All my other testing sites on my localhost work with no blank screen.

When I brought my wordpress blog over to localhost I did

- imported the database to local
- changed site_url and home in wp_options to this `http://localhost:83`
- changed my the connection values in wp-config.php

And I get a blank screen.....Does anyone know why or how to fix it?

In wp-config.php

I turned WP_DEBUG to true and it returned this...

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1038

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=5832 in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1038

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1038

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1038
```

Got my site to appear, but its very messy...here are the errors I get when I turn WP_DEBUG on

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant JQUERYCOLORBOX_TEXTDOMAIN - assumed 'JQUERYCOLORBOX_TEXTDOMAIN' in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-content\plugins\jquery-colorbox\jquery-colorbox.php on line 34

Notice: Constant WPECAUTHNET_PLUGIN_NAME already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-content\plugins\gold_cart_plugin\merchants\wpec_auth_net\wpec_auth_net.php on line 11

Notice: Constant WPECAUTHNET_CLASSES already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-content\plugins\gold_cart_plugin\merchants\wpec_auth_net\wpec_auth_net.php on line 13

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2705

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2705

Notice: Undefined index: authorized in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-content\plugins\wp-login\wp-login.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: scheme in C:\xampp\htdocs\taran\wp-includes\canonical.php on line 398
```

Comment: In your wordpress folder, goto your wp-config file and then change `define("WP_DEBUG", false)` to `define("WP_DEBUG", true)` then go to localhost and then tell us what is on the screen.

Comment: I am not sure what the solution to you're problem is but my suggestion is that you do a fresh install of wordpress on localhost and then import everything over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to wp-config.php, set WP_DEBUG to true and see what happens.

Comment: I think there's a problem with your MySQL server. The database parameters are allright? You can try to restart it.

Comment: Take a look at the XAMPP panel...I don't know it.

Comment: Okay, now I got my site to appear, but now its all messy...I turned on the WP_DEBUG and got a few errors, I will update my question with the errors

Comment: You can ignore those errors. Just set the WP_DEBUG to false and see if your website is working fine

Comment: Nope its still messy, its like the css is not being applied

Comment: OK, then you can check the source code for the CSS file paths. You may have to update the siteurl in wp_options.

Comment: yup css path alll the way, thanks fonini